# Create managed boolean property that is sortable for SPO Search

Tags: sharepoint-online

I need a managed property that is of type `boolean` which is `searchable` and `sortable`.
As none of the OOTB refinables is of bool type, I create a site column on my site that is of type bool.

However, when the property crawls, in the search schema that site column/property is of type "text" even if the site column this property comes from is of type "bool". Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is by default that SharePoint will create a Text managed property(called SiteColumnOWSBOOL) for the boolean site column with values.

You can use value **1** for true and use value **0** for false.